# Updating React state within JavaScript eval()

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, html5-canvas, eval

I'm writing a live-coding web app in React where the user can write javascript code that moves a player icon through a maze. I want to do this all on the frontend, so I'm using `eval()` to run the user's code rather than sending it to a backend for evaluation. I am finding some behavior involving `eval()` and updating graphics/setting state that is causing an issue I can't get around. Below is a simplified version of the functional component in charge of displaying the maze graphics. It accepts the prop `code`, which updates when the user clicks a "run" button.

```
export default function MazeEngine(props) {

        const code = props.code;
        const [player, setPlayer] = useState({position: 0});
        const canvasRef = useRef(null);

          useEffect(() => {
            runCode();
          }, [code])

          useEffect(() => {
            draw(canvasRef.current);
          }, [player])

        const move = () => {
           setPlayer((pl) => {..pl, position: pl+1});
        }

        const sleep = (ms) => {
            var start = new Date().getTime(), expire = start + ms;
            while (new Date().getTime() < expire) { }
            return;
          }
        }

        const runCode = () => {
            eval(code);
        }  

        const draw = (ctx) => { // implementation not shown}

    return(
        <canvas ref={canvasRef} style={{width:350, height:350}}>
    )
}
```

What I have found is that if the user makes multiple calls to `move()`, all of the calls to `setPlayer` are batched for after `eval()` completes. So, for example, if the user writes

```
move();
sleep(1000);
move();
```

the display will update after 1 second, with the player moved two spaces forward. I verified that the effect on `player` is only called once.

Instead, I would like the player to move forward one space, render the new position, wait one second, and move forward another space. That way the user can more easily see the behavior of their algorithm.

#### using references instead of state

I attempted a different approach where I changed player to being a reference with useRef, and called `draw()` directly in the `move` method rather than using `useEffect`. This gave the same problematic behavior - the canvas does not update until the completion of the `eval`.

Comment: The problem is fundamentally not with updating the state, but with your synchronous `sleep` implementation.

Comment: You are correct, I changed sleep to be async using a ```Promise```, and then calling ```await sleep(1000);``` does indeed have the desired effect. Note this also requires wrapping the code inside ```eval``` with an async function call.

Comment: working example in case anyone runs across it: https://gist.github.com/johnpc/8d5740e91d980b8cf7324379ebd574a1